# SHBrowseForFolder not returning Selected folder string by reference

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, reference, pass-by-reference, visual-c++-2010

Hello there I'm working on a windows application using the Windows API with MS VC++ 2010 and I have the following code for selecting folders:

```
BOOL BrowseFolder(TCHAR *result)
{
    BROWSEINFO brwinfo = { 0 };
    brwinfo.lpszTitle = _T("Select Your Source Directory");
    brwinfo.hwndOwner = hWnd;
    LPITEMIDLIST pitemidl = SHBrowseForFolder (&brwinfo);

    if (pitemidl == 0) return FALSE; 

    // get the full path of the folder
    TCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
    if (SHGetPathFromIDList (pitemidl, path)) result = path;

    IMalloc *pMalloc = 0;
    if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetMalloc(&pMalloc)))
    {
        pMalloc->Free(pitemidl);
        pMalloc->Release();
    }

    ::MessageBox(hWnd, result, "input", MB_OK);
    ::MessageBox(hWnd, inputFolder, "input", MB_OK); // Reference Test
    return TRUE;
}
```

So, it opens up a browse folder dialog, saves the selected folder string in the reference parameter "result" and returns true if everything is ok.

Later I call:

```
BrowseFolder(inputFolder);
```

And when i try to print out the content of "inputFolder", it shows blank (inputFolder is a global variable `TCHAR* inputFolder`)

As you can see in the BrowseFolder definition I send two Message Boxes one for "result" and the other for "inputFolder" (this last one shows blank)

So my question is.. If I call: `BrowseFolder(inputFolder);` Shouldn't "inputFolder" be modified by reference? Why does it show empty?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (SHGetPathFromIDList (pitemidl, path)) result = path;
```

This line is your problem. `result` isn't a class like `std::string`, it's simply a pointer to a buffer of one or more `TCHAR`. Assigning it like that simply changes the pointer to point to `path`, it doesn't copy `path` into the buffer that `result` points to.

If you don't want to change to use a `string` class then you need to call a function to copy the string into the supplied buffer. For example:

```
StringCchCopy(result, MAX_PATH, path);
```

(this assumes the buffer is `MAX_PATH` characters in size).

Comment: Yeah it was that, I was changing the the pointer's reference and i didn't see it. The code above worked but I had to change the inputFolder global variable to be a MAX_PATH fixed size array instead of a pointer. Thanks a lot